# tensorflow timeseries different lengths

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I try to get a timeseries into tenserflow to work for an LSTM. I have 4 Files but I'm not sure how to get them together running together. The biggest problem I have is that my first dataset has 1 Data-point per year but 2 others monthly data which should be used for correlation to predict the first set. The 4th Dataset just has some Metadata like Species and Coordinates. Should I put them together somehow, if so how? Any advice in right direction would be nice.
I already looked to the timeseries documentation of tenserflow and also was trying to follow this guide: https://machinelearningmastery.com/multivariate-time-series-forecasting-lstms-keras/
but I struggle with getting the year and month data good together. I manage the data in R but run Tensorflow in Python. I'm more familiar with R in general.

Thank you all for being here!

## Header samples of the Data structure:

**File1.csv:**

```
  years | noaa-tree-2657 |noaa-tree-2658 |noaa-tree-2659 |noaa-tree-2662  
  1901  |       1.676948 |      1.305594 |     0.6756204 |     0.7149572  
  1902  |       1.562344 |      0.899884 |     0.5102933 |     0.6351094  
  1903  |       1.687270 |      1.354678 |     0.9899198 |     0.6158589
```

**File2.csv:**

```
  noaa-tree-2657 |noaa-tree-2658 |noaa-tree-2659 |noaa-tree-2662 |noaa-tree-2664
1           6.41 |          1.85 |          0.33 |          8.61 |          6.07
2          10.45 |          3.20 |          0.38 |          8.58 |          5.30
3          10.81 |          4.30 |          1.50 |          9.34 |          8.50
```

**File3.csv:**

```
  noaa-tree-2657 |noaa-tree-2658 |noaa-tree-2659 |noaa-tree-2662 |noaa-tree-2664
1           -0.3 |          11.0 |          10.1 |         -22.4 |         -15.1
2           -2.9 |          10.2 |           8.8 |         -14.5 |         -13.3
3            1.0 |          14.3 |          14.7 |         -13.8 |         -12.7
```

**File4.csv:**

```
  noaa-tree-2657 |noaa-tree-2658 |noaa-tree-2659 |noaa-tree-2662 |noaa-tree-2664
1           QUPR |          PSME |          PSME |          PCGL |          THOC
2         280.28 |        249.65 |        250.08 |           298 |        280.72
3           39.1 |         31.45 |         32.72 |         56.55 |         48.47
```

Comment: Why is this tagged both R and Python? What have you tried so far, and in which of those languages?

Comment: I use R for the data collection and management but want to run tensorflow in Python. I have a hard time to get started in tensorflow because i don't get how to input data of different length. Just saw the fill up with NA what seems not good.